# What are the IP Address and the Server Address in the Network Settings of Mac OS VPN IkeV2 setting?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, router, vpn

What are the addresses that are listed in the Network Settings of a Mac when the IkeV2 protocol is being used and the computer is connected to a wireless router which is then connected to a modem.  Specifically the "IP Address" towards the top of the image and the Server Address toward the middle of the image.  In addition, why does my IP address show a different IP from the IkeV2 "Server Address" when checking it through a browser.

[image]

Also, why is the IkeV2 setting being listed in the Network Settings of Mac OS, but when using the Open VPN protocol, it doesn't show up here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Specifically the "IP Address" towards the top of the image

VPNs don't simply let you share the server's IP address – their real purpose is to connect you to a faraway network. Within that network, you will usually have an internal IP address exactly like you have one in your actual LAN.

So this 10.76.x address is your computer's internal address in the VPN provider's remote "LAN".

> and the Server Address toward the middle of the image

That's just the actual VPN server you're connected to.

> In addition, why does my IP address show a different IP from the IkeV2 "Server Address" when checking it through a browser.

Two possible reasons:

First, the VPN server can have *more than one* IP address. If it's a public (commercial) service, it's completely possible that the server would have one address for establishing the tunnels and a completely separate address range for outgoing user data. (Yes, it could have a whole address pool if it needs to serve hundreds of users – otherwise it could start running out of TCP ports.)

Second, as I mentioned, VPNs connect you to a *network*, and that means the NAT exit point could be a completely different system than the VPN entry point. For example, your VPN packets are received by server A, but then go through internal routers B and C, before ultimately reaching the external router D which NATs them to some public address. (I would definitely expect something like this on corporate VPNs.)

> Also, why is the IkeV2 setting being listed in the Network Settings of Mac OS, but when using the Open VPN protocol, it doesn't show up here?

The IKEv2 VPN software is part of macOS, meaning that apps can just install a configuration profile and let the OS handle the hard work (speaking the IKE protocol, encrypting packets, etc).

On the other hand, implementing OpenVPN is entirely up to the app itself – macOS doesn't come with built-in support. In this case the app only tells the OS to create a virtual interface for sending packets back and forth, and all of the VPN protocol details remain confined within the app.